# Timer class is causing app crash

Tags: timer

When ever i try to click the button it goes inside the on click method and causes app crash. the timer class is within the on click method.. Please some one help

```
t1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                           decide();
                        }
                    },1000,3000);`
```

`public void decide(){
        rs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot);
        rs.setOnClickListener(this);
        x=r.nextInt(425);
        y=r.nextInt(625);
        rs.setX(x);
        rs.setY(y);
        if (!rs.isPressed())
            s--;
    }`